# Access Leaderboard without user logon

Tags: game-center, leaderboard, game-center-leaderboard

My game, Fire-Balls, uses game centre to populate the leaderboard and also to extract data from leaderboard and show to the user.  This happens when the user has logged on to game centre.

If the user does not log on to the game centre, how do I access the data from game centre?

Objective is to show to user what is on the leaderboard and give an incentive to user to log on to gamecentre.

Please help how this can be done without the user putting his/her credentials to log on game centre

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can't access any data from Game Center if the user has opted out, offline, etc.

You should always check if the GKLocalUser is authenticated and if it isn't disable any Game Center related functionality. In that case it is better to fall back to storing game score, etc. locally (such as in NSUserDefaults).

You shouldn't try to cache any data about remote players locally as it could be seen as harvesting of user data which is not permitted by App Store rules.